# retrieve value from a slick grid table

Tags: javascript, slickgrid

This is how my slick grid table looks like. and the rows are added on the function.
How can I write a function in js to get the `slick-cell l0 r0` value from each class.
 so I want to get `temp,temp2, sss and test33` values

I am new to this slick grid thing so any help will be really appreciated.

```
  <div class="grid-canvas" style="height: 206px; width: 390px;">
    <div class="ui-widget-content slick-row even" style="top:0px">
        <div class="slick-cell l0 r0">temp</div>
        <div class="slick-cell l1 r1">test group</div>
        <div class="slick-cell l2 r2 edit-column"></div>
        <div class="slick-cell l3 r3 delete-column"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="ui-widget-content slick-row odd" style="top:25px">
        <div class="slick-cell l0 r0">temp2</div>
        <div class="slick-cell l1 r1">test g 2 </div>
        <div class="slick-cell l2 r2 edit-column"></div>
        <div class="slick-cell l3 r3 delete-column"></div>
    </div>  
    <div class="ui-widget-content slick-row even" style="top:100px">
        <div class="slick-cell l0 r0">sss</div>
        <div class="slick-cell l1 r1">sss</div>
        <div class="slick-cell l2 r2 edit-column"></div>
        <div class="slick-cell l3 r3 delete-column"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="ui-widget-content slick-row odd" style="top:125px">
        <div class="slick-cell l0 r0">test33</div>
        <div class="slick-cell l1 r1">test33</div>
        <div class="slick-cell l2 r2 edit-column"></div>
        <div class="slick-cell l3 r3 delete-column"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have never used slickgrid, and I don't know if you have any built-in function that helps you, but if you can use plain-old jQuery, you can try it like this:

```
var output = $(".slick-row").find(".l0.r0").map(function () {
  return $(this).text();
}).get();

console.log(output);

// Output will be
// Array[4]
//   0: "temp"
//   1: "temp2"
//   2: "sss"
//   3: "test33"
```

Check this jsFiddle and open the console to see the result:

https://jsfiddle.net/fabio_silva/5n3s6hra/

Comment: I actually have one more class <div class="slick-cell l0 r0 cell-title"> which is getting selected too

Comment: Well, yes, because both cells have the classes `.l0.r0`, so it's being select.
Maybe you should try to explain better what you're trying to accomplish. (This new `.cell-title` is going to appear only on this row, or on all of them?)

Answer (score 0):

you want the first column in every row. Why not use slickgrid's inbuilt functions rather than jquery?